# filter vector in function and return another vector with the filtered results

Tags: c++, vector, filter, stl

i'm working on a class project and i'm stuck on one of the last things i need to do before i'm finished.. The problem is i need to create a function for my custom class (with a vector as one of its elements) that filters the vector of my class and returns another vector with only the matched items of the vector, and this thing has to be done with an STL algorithm, i know im supposed to use remove_if/copy_if but just cant seem to figure out the function that i need to input into the STL filtering algorithm. This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class cityPhone {
private: 
    string cityName;
    string cityCode;
public:
 void setCode(string code){
    cityCode=code;
}
 void setName(string name){
    cityName=name;
}
 cityPhone(){
    cityName="Varna";
    cityCode="0888123123";
}
 cityPhone(string name, string code){
    cityName=name;
    cityCode=code;
}
 string getCity(){
return cityName;    
}
 string getCode(){
    return cityCode;
}
};

bool cmpCity(cityPhone a, cityPhone b)
        {   
            if (a.getCity().compare(b.getCity())>0)return false;
    return true;
        }   

bool cmpCode(cityPhone a, cityPhone b)
        {   
           if (a.getCode().compare(b.getCode())>0)return false;
    return true;
}

 class phoneDirectory {
 private :
     vector<cityPhone> data;
 public:
     phoneDirectory (string path){
        read(path); 
    }
     phoneDirectory (){
        data=vector<cityPhone>();   
    }

   void read(string path){
        cout<<endl;
        try {
string line;
  ifstream myfile (path);
  cityPhone bla = cityPhone();
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        try{
      bla = cityPhone(line.substr(0,line.find_first_of(" ")),line.substr(line.find_first_of(" ")+1));
      data.push_back(bla);
        }
        catch(exception){ }
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
        } catch (exception) {}
}

   void addCityPhone(string city,string phone){
       try{
   data.push_back(cityPhone(city,phone)); 
       }
       catch(exception){
       cout<<"Error adding item "<<endl;
       }
   }

   void delCityPhone(int index){
       try{
   vector<cityPhone>::iterator p=data.begin();
   p+=index;
   data.erase(p);
       } 
       catch(exception){
       cout<<"Error deleting item with index "+index<<endl;
       }
   }

      cityPhone getCityPhone(unsigned index){
       try{
   vector<cityPhone>::iterator p=data.begin();
   p+=index;
   return *p;
       }
       catch(exception){
       cout<<"Error deleting item with index "+index<<endl;
       return cityPhone();
       }
   }

vector<cityPhone>& getData(){
   return data;
}

   void phoneChange(string city, string newPhone){
   try{
       int i=0;
       vector<cityPhone>::iterator p=data.begin();
       for(p=data.begin();p<data.end();p++,i++){
       if (getCityPhone(i).getCity().compare(city)==0){
           string oldPhone = getCityPhone(i).getCode();
           getCityPhone(i).setCode(newPhone);
           cout<<"Phone of city "+city + " was changed from "+oldPhone + " to " + newPhone<<endl;
           return;
       }
       cout<<"No such city exists!\n";
       }
   }
   catch(exception){
   cout<<"Error changing phone"<<endl;
        }
   }

    friend istream& operator>>(ostream& out,phoneDirectory a);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,phoneDirectory a);
 };

istream& operator>>(istream& in,phoneDirectory& a){
    string city,phone;
in >> city >> phone;
a.addCityPhone(city,phone);
return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, cityPhone a){
return out << a.getCity()  <<" " << a.getCode() <<endl;
}

void sortByCity(phoneDirectory &a){
        std::sort(a.getData().begin(),a.getData().end(),cmpCity);
        for(unsigned i=0;i<a.getData().size();i++)
      cout<<a.getCityPhone(i);
       }

void sortByCode(phoneDirectory &a){
        std::sort(a.getData().begin(),a.getData().end(),cmpCode);
        for(unsigned i=0;i<a.getData().size();i++)
      cout<<a.getCityPhone(i);
       }

int main()
{

    phoneDirectory test("C:\\t.txt");

    cin>>test;
    sortByCity(test);
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    sortByCode(test);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm completely stuck, and any help would be greatly appreciated p.s. sorry for the bad english (not my mother language)

Comment: OT: I'm just warning you `cout<<"Error deleting item with index "+index<<endl;` does not do what you think it does. That `+` should be `<<`. This is repeated several times in your code. And I really think you need to decide wether you're reading your directory from a file-based input stream or `std::cin`, because right now you code looks like it tries to do *both*. Also, `data=vector<cityPhone>();` is useless in the default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your phone numbers like this in c++11:

```
std::vector<cityPhone> contacts;
add_contacts(contacts); //add some data
std::vector<cityPhone> varna_contacts;
std::copy_if(contacts.begin(), contacts.end(), std::back_inserter(varna_contacts), 
  [] (const cityPhone& contact) { return contact.getCity() == "Varna"; });
```

or without lambda (c++03):

```
class phoneDirectory {
  static void predicate(const cityPhone& cp) {
    return contact.getCity() == "Varna";
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<cityPhone> contacts;
  add_contacts(contacts); //add some data
  std::vector<cityPhone> varna_contacts;
  std::copy_if(contacts.begin(), contacts.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(varna_contacts), phoneDirectory::predicate);
}
```